# Rail plugin acts_as_taggable_on :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins, acts-as-taggable

I have two models:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_taggable_on :skills, :roles
end
```

I would like to find Employees using the tags associated with their projects.  The geokit-rails plugin supports a similar concept, using its ':through' relationship.

Ideally, I would be able to:

- specify which tags (i.e. skills, roles) would be included in the conditions
- order the employees by the total number of projects with matching tags
- be able to access the matching-tag count for each employee for the purposes of building a tag cloud

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure the acts-as-taggable-on has support for what you looking for directly.  However, you might be able to get at what you want knowing that the acts_as_taggable_on method adds two `has_many` relationships to your `Project` model.  For example, to find employees where the project's skills has some tags you can write

```
Employee.all(:joins => {:projects => :taggings}, :conditions => ['taggings.context = ? and taggings.tag_id in (?)', 'skills', [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42])
```

Of course that requires knowing the tag ids you are interested in, instead if you have the tag names then

```
Employee.all(:joins => {:projects => :base_tags}, :conditions => ['taggings.context = ? and tags.name in (?)', 'skills', ['skill_a', 'skill_b', 'skill_c'])
```

You might be able to expand that to do the different counts you are looking for as well.

Comment: Perhaps I'm making a mistake, but executing ee=Employee.all(:joins => {:projects => :base_tags}, :conditions => ['taggings.context = ? and tags.name in (?)', 'skills', 'oracle']) at the IRB doesn't return anyhting: no errors, no employees, no messages.  This should match a few projects.  I'm also matching the case of the tag name ('skills') and the search value ('oracle'), if that is relevant.  What am I missing?

Comment: This query gives me one Profile record for each matching Project (e.g. if two Projects for a Profile match a tag, you get that Profile repeated twice), rather than a unique list of Profiles that contain a matching Project.  It's a good starting point, however.  What I need is an EXISTS or IN query.